# Hosting SQL Database On-Line

Tags: sql, database

Some software allows you to create your own local database, but the database would be lost in the event of your local computer getting damaged.

So my question is: how to create an on-line SQL database which can be easily queried with software such as MS SQL management studio?

Comment: Pay for a hosted solution. Possibly SQL Server Azure.

Comment: Or Amazon SQL Server (AWS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **pay** companies to host your database, and they give you a connection string to access it from your application or from a tool like SSMS.  Take a look at some examples below...

- [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/)
- [Host-IT](http://www.host-it.co.uk/hosting/Database_options/MSSQLSERVER.asp)
- [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/services/database/mssql/)
- [Discount ASP](http://www.discountasp.net/sp_sqlhosting.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much; that is exactly the kind of information I needed. Apparently the question was considered stupid, but for someone starting from zero it was kind of a big deal. I knew I had to pay, the problem was I was not able to find 'anyone' to pay for this kind of service. In this sense, your list is incredibly useful. Cheers!